# How to add a project as a maven dependency to another project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, dependencies, pom.xml

This is something that has been asked on this forum and other places as well and whilst I have following some of the guides online. I am not being able to find add a new project as a maven dependency into a main project

I have a main_project(comprised of multiple modules and poms)
I have created a new_project that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.project.package</groupId>
    <artifactId>clientinterface</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

</project>
```

I did a `mvn clean install` on the new project and can see it in the **.m2** local repository folder

I have then added the above dependency in the pom file of the main_project
The import is successful and I can also see the dependency in the **External Libraries** section of intelliJ

However, when I try to instantiate a class from this new dependency, it doesn't find the new dependency that I've added

I believe it's not finding the class path but I'm not sure if there are further steps required to update that

As a precaution I also did the following on the new project

```
mvn clean install
```

and maven > **Generate sources and update folders** in intelliJ

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this porblem in the past. Try *Reimport All Maven Projects with IntelliJ*. This is what usually fixes it for me.

[image]